# How many DDR memory chips can be connected to Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC ZCU104

Tags: fpga, ddr, zynq

I have a question regarding Zynq UltraScale+ MPSoC: how many DDR RAMs can be connected to the ZU7EV device, including both PS and PL banks ?

Here is the link for [TRM](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug1085-zynq-ultrascale-trm.pdf).

Comment: Needs clarification. Your question is incomplete. What do you mean by "DDR RAMs"? Memory chips come with different bus widths. You can connect many 4bit chips, or a few 16bit chips. For example.

Comment: @TimmyBrolin How many of DDR SDRAMS (of 64bit width, 2GB size) can be connected to zc104 kit (features Zynq UltraScale+ XCZU7EV-2FFVC1156 MPSoC) device.